# Javascript-HTML - how to iterate through all the forms on a page?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-traversal

How can I iterate through all forms in a document using javascript?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The code below will go through an html document, get all forms and do a pop-up alert of the names of each form.

```
var formsCollection = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
for(var i=0;i<formsCollection.length;i++)
{
   alert(formsCollection[i].name);
}
```

This is just a start to see if you are getting the reult you require. Thereafter, remove the alert and continue to do what you need to.

Comment: Obviously because your answer is less elegant then pulse .. I didn't give you vote down btw

Comment: I didn't vote, but note that the "name" attribute has little use on a form, so you'll seldom see it. One would find the uniqueness and addressability of "id" to be more useful, but neither affect the form's functionality.

Answer (score 16):

You can use

`document.forms` collection

See [forms Collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/forms)

Comment: this should be best answer :)

Comment: Much simpler than trying to grab the element by the Tag, ID, or Name as they could be different.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example using the document.forms instead of getElementsByTagName().

As with the getElementsByTagName() example this goes through all the forms and does a popup alert with the action (instead of name, as it is more likely to be set).

```
var formsCollection;
var r;

formsCollection=document.forms;

for(r=0;r<formsCollection.length;r++)
{
    alert(formsCollection[r].action);
}
```

This can be condensed down and of course the popup changed to something useful but I have tried to keep it simple.

And for reference here are some links to more info:

- [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.forms)
- [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537457%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- [w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-1689064)
- And even [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_doc_forms.asp)