# javascript: why won't this cause all the forms on a page to reset?

Tags: javascript, forms, reset

good evening fellow code bashers:

i know it should be simple, but i'm tired and just want to get it done.  this is how i thought it should be done, which is identical to [how this fellow did it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146348/javascript-html-how-to-iterate-through-all-the-forms-on-a-page), *BUT* `numberOfForms` comes up ZERO, instead of THREE (that's how many forms are on the page, all named & id'd).  what did i miss?

```
var numberOfForms = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
console.log("numberOfForms: " + numberOfForms);
for (var i=0; i<numberOfForms.length; i++)
{
  document.forms[i].reset;
}
```

shed some light, plz.  then i can punch out and hit the hay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.  You have already got an array with all HTML DOM Form elements.  Use `numberOfForms[i].reset()` instead of trying to use `document.forms[n]`.

```
var numberOfForms = document.getElementsByTagName("form"); 
console.log("numberOfForms: " + numberOfForms); 
for (var i=0; i<numberOfForms.length; i++) 
{ 
   numberOfForms[i].reset();
}
```

Actually this is cleaner and more efficient, there is actually no need to traverse the DOM with `document.getElementsByTagName()`

```
var allForms = document.forms;
for (var i=0; i < allForms.length; i++) {
  allForms[i].reset();
}
```

Comment: you're trying to reset the collection? That won't work... I think it's a typo though... looks like you meant numberOfForms[i].reset

Comment: Think you may be missing a `[i]` in there :)

Comment: @Dr.Dredel.  Yes I was aware of my typo and was in the process of correcting it.

Comment: @Gabe...Rob is speaking of using `document.forms` to generate the array of forms and not using `document.getElementsByTagName("form")`.  Because the latter is just excess, you do not need to traverse the DOM to get all form elements.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `reset()`

```
var numberOfForms = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
console.log("numberOfForms: " + numberOfForms);
for (var i=0; i<numberOfForms.length; i++)
{
  document.forms[i].reset();
}
```

Comment: this is the right answer. reset is just a reference to the function.  reset() will run the function