# Reset all fields (checkbox, text, select) with <body onload();">

Tags: javascript, page-refresh

I'm trying to clear all fields on a page but I don't want a reset button. I just want people to hit F5, refresh, etc.

**I am trying to use this...**

```
<body onload="MM_preloadImages('../images/PrintButtonWhite.png'); document.CourseMenu.reset();">
```

to clear my entire form of checkboxes, dropdown menus, and text boxes. It's not working.

**Also tried this...**

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.CourseMenu.reset();</script>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `reset` resets a form to its initial state. If that state is pre-filled, then they will be pre-filled.

Comment: It is not a pre-filled form. Checkboxes are unchecked, dropdowns are un-selected, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Is `CourseMenu` the ID of your `form`? If so, try this:

```
document.getElementById('CourseMenu').reset();
```

Comment: CourseMenu is the name of the <div> tag where the form sits... I tried that, but it didn't work. Is there something that would just refresh the entire website, and reset all fields... not just the form?

Comment: Do you have input, etc. fields that aren't contained in a `form` element? If so, you'll have to clear the values manually. If not, this question/answer has what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7801749/javascript-why-wont-this-cause-all-the-forms-on-a-page-to-reset

Comment: Now, I've learned it's only happening in IE8 and the latest version of FF. It doesn't happen in Chrome though. IE8 is our corporate browser, so I have to make adjustments for it. Here's the page [here](http://webfro.gs/south/toc2/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a Util object. I did this because I use not only trivial html control I use also datepicker and boostrap switches so you have to do it manually. I remove all extra code and let to work with the basic, with this you will have totally control on what are you reseting.. I think you also can send a contair value not a form and will work like a `<div>` havent tested.

-- Edit --
You can send the continer like Util.resetForm($("#myid")); without caring if it `form` or other `special tag`

You can start with this...  just use the function on the onload method

try for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/ncubica/DGMAC/

```
function reset(objectHTML) {
    objectHTML.find("input, textarea,select").not("input[type=submit]").each(function (_index, _item) {
        //field is going to evalute ?        
        if (typeof $(_item).attr("data-ignore") === "undefined") {             
            switch(_item.type){
                case "text":
                    $(_item).val("");
                    break;
                case "checkbox":
                    $(_item).removeAttr("checked");                    
                    break;
                case "select":
                    $(_item).prop("selectedIndex", -1);                    
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
};

$("#test").one("click",function(){
  reset($("#myform"))
});
```

You can add the tag data-ignore="ignore" to dont let the script reset the value this is useful when you dont wan to lose the index of some select

all the `select` tags will appear on blank after running this script without any selection on it..

//this can be improve with a switch .. but, I'm just showing how can it works..

Comment: This didn't work either. Did you see my other comment about IE8. It's our corporate browser, so it has to work there, too... seems like an awful lot of code just to refresh a page, and it's fields.

Comment: I change the code, but! just have to understand this code is also to reset control whit are not just browser controls special controls like boostrap controls etc. take another test on fiddle is using jQuery

Comment: Is just a warp object where you can have other static method that you use in coding ... ok i will puttin in a straight function wait...

Comment: Okay... what am I putting in the #test and #myform fields? [Here](http://webfro.gs/south/toc2/) the site the way it is with your function in it... Where am I going wrong? Try to view it in IE8, if you can. It's where I'm having the trouble.

Comment: Are you still with me?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33816/discussion-between-ncubica-and-webfrogs)